# Проблема с выводом видео в автозапуске в Raspberry что стоит сделать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

есть проблема при автозапуске программы с захватом видео с камеры. сам скрипт на запуск программы работает на что указывают логи(фото предоставляю), но при попытке вывести видео выдаёт ошибку которая насколько я понял связана с CV2. Код также предоставляю

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
print ("Hello World!")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320) 
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
while True:
    flag, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего автозапуск исполнен без дисплейной сессии.

Реализуйте автологин в дисплейную сессию и уже там настройте автозапуск.